# Multiple table updates from one source list in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 3 tables that I wish to `UPDATE` data against (lets call them `PROCESS`, `DIARY` and `HISTORY`)

The 3 tables all have an ID column and the subset of data I wish to update is retrieved from a `SELECT` statement against the `PROCESS` table

```
SELECT ID FROM PROCESS WHERE STATUS = 1 AND COMPANY = 'XYZ'
```

Using T-SQL, I was planning to do 3 `UPDATE` statements (with the `PROCESS` table being last as it is the reference list) like so

```
UPDATE HISTORY ... WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM PROCESS WHERE STATUS = 1 AND COMPANY = 'XYZ')
UPDATE DIARY ... WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM PROCESS WHERE STATUS = 1 AND COMPANY = 'XYZ'
)
UPDATE PROCESS ... WHERE STATUS = 1 AND COMPANY = 'XYZ'
```

My question is: is this the most efficient way to do this within T-SQL - or should I be creating some sort of CTE to reference only once? (The number of documents/performance are not a problem, I'm just trying to find out if as an ex OO developer coming to SQL, I'm slipping into bad habits or missing a trick somewhere

Comment: Using 3 separate updates statements is the best approach if not by performance by robustness. Also think about the bad time engine ill get if it needs to realize if update in first table affects the other update statement. This only can disallow any sort of "one line, multiple updates" since it can lead to nasty effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to use CTE as CTE can be referenced only once. Updating 3 tables requires 3 separate queries to be run.

If obtaining the ID's in your inner query is expensive, you may consider running the query to get them only once and storing the results in a temporary table or table variable. This way you will be able to reference that temporary table or table variable in all update statements.

If the inner query is inexpensive to run, I would leave it as is to not complicate things unnecessarily.

Comment: Thanks @szymon - always good to know I'm not going completely down the wrong track on my approach.